# JQuery Validate Plugin: make input required depending on radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm having a real headache trying to get the jQuery Validate plugin to work.

I have a form, the first question asking the user to select an option from a radio group. This shows further questions below, depending on their selection.

What I'm trying to achieve is making the visible questions required, but obviously depending on what the user chose at the first question - ie. if the question isn't visible then don't require it.

The form can be seen here:
http://planner.adamturtle.com/index.php?id=cab11f902671b3c2d6&page=2

All the javascript code is embedded on the page.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The embeded javascript is a bit confusing (in that I couldn't understand it immediately... but then again i'm somewhat new to jQuery) - I would suggest removing all attempts of doing this so as people can see which elements of your code actually work.

Answer (score 2):

To gather visible elements:

```
$currentInputs = $("input:visible");
```

What I would do for readability purposes is assign all "active" inputs to be validated with a class like "validateMe":

```
$currentInputs = $("input.validateMe");
$result = $currentInputs.validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery validate plugin allows you to add a custom validation methods and you may want to try those. Inside this method you can check when is the value of the radio box and check other field values based on that information.

The method to add a custom validation is called `addMethod` (docs link [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage)).

Answer (score 0):

If all questions are required - no matter what - you could probably just validate *all* fields.

But this would only work if you used some kind of ajax call to populate the forms.  This way it's not trying to validate the questions that are not displayed.

Ex: have a string that contains the HTML you'd like to embed.

```
var formString1 = '<input type="text" name="thisInput" />';
    formString1 = '<input type="radio" name="anotherInput" />;
    ...
```

and then inject each form string into the given forms.

OR

send out a request to validate the forms with `class="required"`.  Which you can add depending on which radio button is clicked.

jQuery:

```
validate($(.required));

function validate(elements){
   $.ajax( //send request to validate 'elements );
}
```

It's a bit dirty, doesn't use the form validator plug-in and none of these are tested, but it might give you some direction.

***EDIT:***
Do you have a set system for the PHP backend validation?

Comment: Hi Derek,

Thanks for your reply.

I'm sure this is possible using the validation plugins methods, so if there's a solution that way it'd be much better.

I agree with your comment about removing previous attempts, I'll take those out.

The PHP backend was written by me, and is very basic as I'm not a developer. I don't even think I have server side validation built in yet! That's not a priority right now, though.

Comment: Server-side validation is imperative for a live application.  If you rely purely on javascript for input validation - it is possible to inject malicious content simply by disabling javascript.  If you are looking for something within the jQuery validation it seems like you need to check out the documentation link that RaYell provided.